# how use np.append with np.where method?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert this code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [np.nan,-1.2,3,6,7,2]})

def f_evol (df) : 
list1 = []  
for i in range (len(df)) : 
    if df['values'].isnull()[i] : 
        list1.append(0)
    else : 
        if df['values'][i] > 0 : 
            k = list1[i-1] + 1
            list1.append(k)
        if df['values'][i] < 0: 
            k = list1[i-1] - 1 
            list1.append(k)
return list1

df['count'] = f_evol(df)
```

on this one :

```
def v_evol (df) :
k = [1]
a = np.where(df['values'].isnull().shift(0).values, 
             k,
             np.where(df['values'].shift(0).values > 0,
                      k.append(k[-1] + 1),
                      np.where(df['values'].shift(0).values < 0, 
                              k.append(k[-1] - 1),
                              np.nan
                              )
                     )
            )
return a
```

i failed to append the last value of k like in the first code ...
i tried, to replace ‘*k[0] + 1*’ by ‘np.concatenate()’, by ‘np.append()’ without succes... b

Comment: What are you trying to do with `k[0]+1`?  If `k` is an array, this adds (numerically) 1 to the value.  It is not an 'append'.  Don't try to "grow" numpy arrays like you do with lists.  `np.append` is not a list append clone.  Don't try to use it.

Comment: thx for your return. 
my objective it's to find a way to build a column/list/array with a method inside np.where like list.append work in the first code.
I need to use the last value of this list to generate the next one.

Comment: I didn't ask about the overall objective!

Comment: ok so i use k[0] +1 to 'imitate' list1[i-1] and obviously, this slicing is not the solution...

Comment: `where` is not an iterator.  The 3 arguments should be arrays/series (which are evaluated before being passed to the function).  And it it returns a new array.  In `pandas` it is used to evaluate all rows of at once (in parallel), not sequentially.

Comment: ok !!! 
And do you know which numpy method, or something else, can i use to process this iteration ?
I work on a deep dataframe, and the time of calcul with for loop are very slow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With numpy

This will give you want you want without any explicit iteration (generally, you want to avoid `for` loops when working with arrays and dataframes):

```py
np.sign(df["values"].fillna(0)).cumsum()
```

Demo:

```py
In [3]: df["count"] = np.sign(df["values"].fillna(0)).cumsum()

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   values  count
0     NaN    0.0
1    -1.2   -1.0
2     3.0    0.0
3     6.0    1.0
4     7.0    2.0
5     2.0    3.0
```

You can certainly cast the `"count"` column to an integer `dtype` if you want.

### Without numpy

This will produce the same result without the numpy dependency, if that matters:

```py
(df["values"] // df["values"].abs()).fillna(0).cumsum()
```